# why we randomly pointing to wrong dfs share (something wrong with our setting)?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

I am a developer, not an IT guy, but really get annoyed by our DFS share and IT isn't able to find a solution at the moment.

We have two sites (A and B). DFS share is setup to replicate files between the two. Say the dfs server in Site A is dfsSA and in site B is dfsSB and the share is \webfund\myshare.

The idea is that if my local server is running in site A, I should connect to dfs server in Site A, otherwise in Site B.

Randomly what we see are:
1. even the local server is in site A, when accessing \webfund\myshare, it goes to the dfs server in share B.
2. Some files are only available in Site A and failed to be replicated into Site B.

Can someone explain why this can happen? 
Is there a way to force either a local server always connects to Site A?
Is it possible to force the files get replicated again manually (for the ones failed to copy over)?

Comment: DFS is no small area I'm afraid it is quite complex however some advice that may or may not be helpful. DFS is fully Active Directory dependant. Within AD you have sites which are broke down to Subnets if they are setup (and setup correctly!) so depending on what subnet you are on should place you on your local DFS Server. Now in terms of replication issues DFS can stop replicating and show no signs (nothing in event logs, etc.) using the command line tool dfsradmin on both the DFS Servers you can view any backlog using the backlog switch which might be the cause.

Comment: I would expect the share name to have three levels: domain\dfsroot\sharename. Is this not the case? Also, DFS replication and DFS namespace are almost completely unrelated. It helps to bear this in mind when troublehshooting.